# PHPmailer : Showing a weird text before sending a mail?

Tags: php, phpmailer

My problem is clear, PHPmailer is howing a long text before sending a mail, this is my code (function) :

```
    function sendMail($content){

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->Port=465;                              // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'my mail';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '*****';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->SMTPDebug=true;
$mail->From = '****';
$mail->FromName = '******';
$mail->addAddress('******');  
$mail->Subject = 'subject';

$mail->Body=$content;

$mail->AltBody ='testing';
$stat=$mail->send();
}
```

and this is a screenshot :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mm749.jpg

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry guys, I noticed that I should turn off debugging :

```
$mail->SMTPDebug=false;
```

Comment: `SMTPDebug` is an integer value; setting it to false or true is equivalent to the 0 and 1 debug levels (by normal type casting), but suggests you don't know that there are higher levels.